# Doctrine query distinct related entity

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, dql

I'm probably overlooking something very simple and just been staring at it too much, but I can't get this DQL query to work. I get an exception stating:

```
Cannot select entity through identification variables without choosing at least one root entity alias.
```

Here's my query. User has a many-to-one relation to Group. Note that this is a unidirectional relation! That may make no sense to you, but it makes sense in our domain logic.

```
SELECT DISTINCT g
FROM Entity\User u
LEFT JOIN u.group g
WHERE u.active = :active
```

Can you tell me what I am missing here?

Comment: Isn't missing an `ON` here after the LEFT JOIN?

Comment: No. This is Doctrine DQL, not SQL.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I worked around the problem by doing a subselect:

```
SELECT g
FROM Entity\Group
WHERE g.id IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT g2.id
    FROM Entity\User u
    LEFT JOIN u.group g2
    WHERE u.active = :active
)
```

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I do seem to remember running into that once. Kindof an annoying workaround.

Answer (score 16):

Since this is the first Google match when searching for the error message *"Cannot select entity through..."*, I decided to respond despite the topic was posted few months ago.

The trick is to use JOIN ... WITH ... (like JOIN ... ON ... in SQL).

I was having the message with this code:

```
SELECT ro, COUNT(ro)
FROM FH\MailerBundle\Entity\Recipient r
JOIN r.selectedOption ro
GROUP BY ro.id
```

I solved the problem by this code:

```
SELECT ro, COUNT(ro)
FROM FH\MailerBundle\Entity\RecipientOption AS ro
JOIN FH\MailerBundle\Entity\Recipient AS r WITH r.selectedOption = ro
GROUP BY ro.id
```

I needed to specify full namespaces and classes for both entities.

Answer (score 7):

You need to select FROM the `root entity alias`.. meaning you can't SELECT *only* from a table you're joining on, as you can in plain sql.. so something like this should do it:

```
SELECT DISTINCT g
FROM Entity\Group g
INNER JOIN g.user u
WHERE u.active = :active
```

Comment: Oops, a transcription error on my part. My apologies. My actual entities are named differently, though their relation (and the rest of the DQL) is the same.

Comment: Ah, in that case, it's complaining about you querying FROM Users, but not including the Users Entity in the SELECT portion of your query, hence the `at least one root entity alias` in your warning - root entity alias just means *what's in your FROM clause*, for all intensive purposes.. I've updated my answer

Comment: And that's the exact problem. My domain model says that the relationship is uni-directional so I can't query from the other side like you are doing here. I worked around it by doing a subselect.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem and solved it by multiple `from` calls, like this:

```
$this->getDoctrine()->createQueryBuilder()
    ->from('ProjectMainBundle:Group', 'g')
    ->from('ProjectMainBundle:User', 'u')
    ->select('distinct(g)')
    ->where('u.group = g')
    ->andWhere('u.active = :active')
    ->....
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using DQL's new **WITH** keyword:

```
SELECT DISTINCT g
FROM Entity\User u
LEFT JOIN Entity\Group g
WITH u in g.users
WHERE u.active = :active
```

Answer (score 2):

I use this

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('o')
           ->select('DISTINCT IDENTITY(o.user)')
```

Comment: You are querying not an entity in a whole, but only it's identity.